# c memcpy struct by value

Tags: c, memcpy

Im simply trying to copy one struct to another (copy by value, NOT by reference). Here is fully working code

```
/* memcpy example */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define SIZE (80*sizeof(char))

typedef struct {
    char* name;
} person;

int main ()
{
  person p1;
  p1.name = (char*) malloc( SIZE );

  person p2;
  p2.name = (char*) malloc( SIZE );

  // set p1
  strcpy(p1.name, "John");

  // copy p1 > p2
  memcpy ( &p2, &p1, SIZE );

  printf ("p1.name: %s (%u)\n", p1.name, &p1.name );
  printf ("p2.name: %s (%u)\n", p2.name, &p2.name );

  // change p1 only
  printf("Changing p1.name\n");
  strcpy(p1.name, "ONLY p1.name Changed");

  // now, why did p2 change?
  printf ("p1.name: %s (%u)\n", p1.name, &p1.name );
  printf ("p2.name: %s (%u)\n", p2.name, &p2.name );

  free(p1.name);
  free(p2.name);

  return 0;
}
```

Here is a fiddle http://cpp.sh/57skb

That code outputs

```
p1.name: John (0x791b3cdd6270)
p2.name: John (0x791b3cdd6280)
Changing p1.name
p1.name: ONLY p1.name Changed (0x791b3cdd6270)
p2.name: ONLY p1.name Changed (0x791b3cdd6280)
```

Expected output would be

```
p1.name: John (0x791b3cdd6270)
p2.name: John (0x791b3cdd6280)
Changing p1.name
p1.name: ONLY p1.name Changed (0x791b3cdd6270)
p2.name: John (0x791b3cdd6280)
```

Question: why does **p2** change?

Note that doing the same thing without struct works as expected:
http://cpp.sh/6qevd

Comment: @WhozCraig There is the code included. You shouldn't downvote for that, your comment would have been enough.

Comment: Who said I down-voted *anything* ? I didn't. I don't down-vote questions. If they suck so bad/ill-prepared they deserve a down-vote I'll just vote to close them instead (which I didn't do here). Whomever down-voted your question, look elsewhere, because it wasn't me.

Comment: @WhozCraig I assumed wrong, sorry.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you make that copy then both structure `name` member will have the same value so they point to the same memory location. Your code does not show this since you does not print the pointer value properly. Try this to see that they are indeed the same

```
  printf ("p1.name: %s (%p)\n", p1.name, p1.name );
  printf ("p2.name: %s (%p)\n", p2.name, p2.name );
```

Output

```
p1.name: John (0x3ee8d60)
p2.name: John (0x3ee8d60)
```

`p2` does not change after `strcpy(p1.name, "ONLY p1.name Changed");`. Simply `p2.name` points to this new string also.

Answer (score 2):

If you just copy the struct, then you're overwriting the pointer, not what it points to. What you probably want to do instead of your memcpy is this:

```
size_t bytes = strlen(p1.name)+1;
p2.name = realloc(p2.name, bytes);
if (p2.name != NULL) {
    memcpy(p2.name, p1.name, bytes);
}
```

Here, `bytes` is the number of characters in the name plus the string nul-terminator, and the call to `realloc` changes the size of p2.name to match it. Now, guaranteed that there's enough spoace, you can `memcpy` the first name into the second.

Using realloc here is probably inefficient, because it preserves the original content of p2.name, which we don't need. An alternative would be to free the old string first, before allocating space for the new one:

```
size_t bytes = strlen(p1.name)+1;
free(p2.name);
p2.name = malloc(bytes);
if (p2.name != NULL) {
    memcpy(p2.name, p1.name, bytes);
}
```

Beware that both malloc and realloc can fail, and will return NULL if your program runs out of memory, so it's good practice to always check for that.

Answer (score 1):

you need to copy the allocated memory areas not the structs itself

```
memcpy ( p2.name, p1.name, SIZE );
```